# Meyer lemon tree coming back to life

Tags: indoors

I over watered my July purchased Meyer lemon tree when I brought it in from outdoors in the fall.  It bloomed and began to make lemons when all of a sudden every leaf fell off. I think it had root rot.   I repotted in new  soil and I have kept it fed all winter and under watered it and now it looks like it’s starting to grow a lot of new blooms.  But there are no leaves?  How can it bloom with no leaves?  What is my next course of action?  Thank you for any help

Comment: Many thanks for your hopeful response

Answer (score 1):

The first citrus tree i got from the nursery had lots of blooms but no leaves. After a few weeks when all the blooms were spent came the leaves. I didn't know much about citrus trees at that time so i thought it was normal for it to bloom first and then set leaves like so many other fruit trees do but ever since then, it has never acted like this and has always produced new leaves and blossoms pretty much at the same time with the older leaves turning yellow and falling off so i shouldn't be worried for as long as the tree is getting adequate sunlight and is not being overwatered or over fed.

Comment: Thank you. Hoping for success